# Validate typescript, but don't build it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a folder called "__ tests __".

I want it to be validated as typescript, but I don't want to build that folder. ( I don't want it to go to **dist** folder )

How would I do that?

It's like I have to include it, but not really...

My ts.config.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES2017",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.json", "__tests__/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply use the option `noEmit` in your use case to not emit the output.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "noEmit": true,
  }
}
```

#### Update for only emitting in test case

I think you can also go for creating the new configuration for testing files to `include` only your test code extending from the current one.

`tsconfig.test.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  {
   "compilerOptions": {
      "noEmit": true,
    },
   "include": [
      "__tests__", // your test file
   ],
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test:typeCheck": "tsc --project tsconfig.test.json"
  }
}
```

- Type check your test folder without emitting: `npm run test:typeCheck`
- Run build to emit files normally: `npm build`

Comment: I do want to emit src folder that i have. I don't want to emit __tests__ folder. Both are in the same root folder.

Comment: I've dropped you another suggestion by adding to the answer

Comment: that does not emit any build...I want to emit src and I don't want to emit __ tests __ folder...

Comment: I edited the answer for you again. Please pay attention in detail what I explained

Comment: I landed here just wanting to use tsc on the cli and omit the emission, so though this doesn't answer the question this may help someone: `npx tsc --noEmit` You could also throw the `--noEmit` flag into your package.json scripts as well.